# How shall I control going to previous page?

Tags: php, html

```
<html> 
<body>
<form action="index.php">
        <button type="submit" name="logout" style="background:lawngreen ;" 
class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
    </form>`
<?php
$btn=$_POST['logout'];
if(isset($btn))
{
 header("location:index.php");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click logout button, the page will be redirected to index.php and when I 
click back(<-) button the page still moves to previous page. Can anyone give 
solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should in generally redirect back if the user is not logged in anymore.
If you do this and the user visits a restricted page after logout again he should be redirected to the login page everytime as long as hes not logged in.

logout.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = false;
```

restricted-access-page.php

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) || $_SESSION["loggedIn"] !== true) {
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

must use the Session it will help to you

https://www.guru99.com/cookies-and-sessions.html

first, you want to destroy session while clicking the logout button 
and after then add the Session is there or not using `if statement` 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp